# Import product file downloads

Tags: 7, ubercart, feeds

I am currently using the module (uc_feeds_product_importer.zip) suggested on this link https://drupal.org/node/1802908 to import products. Using this above module there is no access to import product file downloads.

uc_feeds module does a great job by providing access to import product attributes. How to update/enhance this module to import file download feature as well?

Comment: I tried adding below mentioned code

    $targets['uc_file_model'] = array(
    'name' => t('UC: File SKU'),
    'callback' => 'uc_feeds_set_target',
    'description' => 'Ubercart:' . t('File SKU'),
    );`

I can able to see the option while editing the 'Feeds importers > Node process > Mapping' option but when the option is mapped to field and when a csv is imported the product file download feature is not updated

Comment: I have the same problem as you, I can not map the document has downloaded
Have you found a solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: I still have not found the solution for this issue... Instead I ended up building a portal for it